# Google Maps custom maker doesn't appear on my server, but works on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to create a custom map where I'm going to set a few markers with a custom icon. The icon appear normally on my localhost but when I uploaad all the files to my server the custom icon doesn't appear! The map show the default GMap marker proving that my database connection is ok. Here follow my code:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var allMarkers = [];
        var customIcons = {
            0: {
                icon: location.origin + '/mymap/images/mm_20_green.png'
            },
            1: {
                icon: location.origin + '/mymap/images/mm_20_red.png'
            }
        };
        function setMarkers(data) {
            console.log('setMarkers');
            console.log(data);
            var markerJson = JSON.parse(data);

            var pos;
            var marker;
            var icon;

            for (var i = 0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
                allMarkers[i].setMap(null);
            };

            allMarkers = [];

            console.log(markerJson.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < markerJson.length; i++) {
                icon = customIcons[markerJson[i].stat] || {};                   
                pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markerJson[i].lat, markerJson[i].lng);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Title',
                    icon: icon.icon
                });

                allMarkers.push(marker);
                console.log(allMarkers);
            }
        }

        function fetchMarkers() {
            console.log('fetchMarkers');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "jsonResponse.php",           
                success: function(data) {
                    setMarkers(data);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        fetchMarkers();
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
        }

        function initialize() {
            console.log('initialize');
            // Get center
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                panControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };
            // Load google map
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

            if(navigator.geolocation) {
              browserSupportFlag = true;
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
              }, function() {
                handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
              });
            }

            fetchMarkers();
        }

        function loadScript() {                
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
        window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

jsonResponse.php:

```
<?php

require("config.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect (DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM sensors WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$markersArray = array();

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  array_push($markersArray, $row);
}

echo json_encode ($markersArray);
```

I'm pretty sure the icon image is in the right place. I just copy and paste to the server, so the files structure is exactly the same.

Anyone have any ideia about what should I do? I'm starting to think it is about server configuration...

Comment: @KimGysen the deafult marker from GMap is been ploted on the map correctly I just can't change it to my custom marker on the server (localhost is ok).

Comment: Nothing changes, @KimGysen

Comment: Strange that it did work on your localhost. Usually you will get an error in the console if the icon cannot be found. What happens if you try to put the hard coded path immediately into the marker as you instantiate it?

Comment: Oh! doing so, it works! weird...

Comment: The most weird thing is that the same code works on localhost but doesn't on remote server... I'm debugging using `console.log(icon.icon)` and on localhost `icon.icon` print the icon link correctly, but on my server, it says `icon.icon` is unreachable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably having a problem with this line:

`icon = customIcons[markerJson[i].stat] || {};`

`markerJson[i]` is an item that you get back from the server, and `stat` should be 0 or 1 according to your code.
If it's not, you will get an empty object, which means that you won't be able to get the icon property of the empty object.

Comment: This is almost exactly the problem... Turns out that not everything was identical to my localhost. I changed one column name on localhost database and I forgotten to change it on my server... your answer helped me to figure this out. Thank you!